# Is it fuselage for a spaceship?

Tags: word-choice

When you mention the body of planes, you call it the fuselage.

When the vehicle is a ship, you call it a hull.

What about the body of spaceships? Fuselage? Suppose the Enterprise NCC1701 ship, for example.

Comment: [Usage comparison chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spaceship+hull%2Cspaceship+fuselage&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: You might get more knowledgeable answers at [space.SE].

Comment: Fuselage specifically means the main body of a plane, excluding wings (and anything attached to them). And hull of a ship excludes the superstructure. So it would depend on your spacecraft design. Are we talking a modern rocket, a space probe, a crew capsule, a space shuttle, or something wild and science fiction-related?

Comment: Does this spaceship enter an atmosphere ?  Or is it purely a vacuum vessel?   Enterprise was built in space, and only the saucer ever passed through an atmosphere.

Comment: A hint is contained in the word "space **ship**"....

Comment: @FumbleFingers It didn't show anything for _spaceship hull_, so I tried [replacing _spaceship_ with _spacecraft_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spacecraft+hull%2Cspacecraft+fuselage&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) and got results for both hull and fuselage. I guess it means that a spacecraft can have a hull or a fuselage, but if something is big enough to be called _spaceship_, then it clearly has a hull?

Comment: @Frax: Given that ***hull*** is several times more common than ***fuselage*** after ***spacecraft*** anyway (and that there are a couple of written instances of ***lunar module hull*** in Google Books, but none at all for ***lunar module fuselage***), I think *as a non-native Anglophone*, all the OP here needs to know is that he can't go wrong if he sticks with ***hull***.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on whether you want the reader to think of the vessel as a ship or an airplane.

I'm really not being glib here -- if you're talking science fiction, then we usually would use 'hull' for large space vessels that we treat like ocean-going ships (including the Enterprise or the Millennium Falcon, or even a shuttlecraft), and we'd probably talk about the fuselage for something we want to think of like an airplane (such as an X-wing).

Generally, if you can get up and walk around inside it (or, you know, float), it's probably a hull.

In terms of modern spacecraft like Apollo or Dragon, I don't think there really IS a standardized term for it. "Skin" comes up a lot, but that usually refers to the very outermost layer rather than the structure as a whole.

Comment: Other words seen to describe the outer layer of a spaceship or satellite is **skin** or **shell**.

Comment: Remember the etymology of fuselage:  French _fuselé_ "spindle-shaped"

Comment: Current spacecraft seem most commonly to be referred to as "capsules", or "modules"

Comment: I’ve also occasionally heard the term ‘spaceframe’ (as an analogue to ‘airframe’ from aviation), though that’s both ambiguous (it has a different meaning in real-world structural engineering) and would (again by analogy with ‘airframe’) refer to the entire body and structure of the spacecraft, not just the outer hull.

Comment: @MikeB Right, but "capsule" or "module" refers to the whole thing -- analogous to "ship" or "airplane" (or maybe "speedboat" or "fighter jet" since you could refer to them all as spacecraft). There doesn't seem to be a word used specifically to refer to the structural shell of the thing.

Comment: Note that a sufficiently destructive aircraft crash is called a hull-loss accident. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hull_loss

Comment: Huh!  I've heard that term but I thought they were saying 'whole-loss'. (But most people seem to just call it getting totaled!)

Answer (score 7):

#### What shape is your spacecraft?

The word "fuselage" means "spindle-shaped".  It means the approximately-cylindrical section of a conventional aircraft where the people sit.  And crucially, it only applies to aircraft with a well-defined approximately-cylindrical body section.  If you don't have a well-defined approximately-cylindrical body section, then by definition you don't have a fuselage.  You have an aircraft (or spaceship) body of some other shape, sure - but it is not a fuselage.

Is this merely pedantry about the word's origin?  Actually no, because we have a real life example.  A [flying wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_wing) aircraft is literally defined by the fact that it is an aircraft with a lifting wing but *without* a fuselage.

Unless there is some good handwavy reason for your spaceships to have a similar shape to a present-day aircraft (and in space opera there's always Rule of Cool!) then your spaceships probably aren't a spindle-shaped design with wings.  More likely they'll be brick-shaped, or spherical, or just any random shape that happens to hold everything together.  At that point "hull" is probably a better description of the outer envelope of the spacecraft than anything else.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, by the answers here, I am convinced that “my” spacecraft has a hull, instead of a fuselage 

Comment: Extending that thought - the Space Shuttle would have a hull, while it's big orange tank and the two solid rocket boosters would have a fuselage?

Comment: @YPOC Since it was designed to look (and in some ways perform) like a regular aircraft, the Space Shuttle had a fuselage (the central body section) and wings.

Comment: So a TIE fighter doesn't have a fuselage then?

Comment: @Graham Is the Space Shuttle controlled from a bridge or a cockpit?

Comment: @DarthPseudonym According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIE_fighter) it has a cockpit and hull, not a fuselage, which ties in with the description of a fuselage.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Why would that be relevant to anything? To answer your question though, it had a cockpit or flight deck, like an aircraft.

Answer (score 3):

The NCC1701 is, of course, not a "real" spacecraft.  In the TV series the word "hull" tended to be used.  The show's writers tended to use terminology borrowed from navies and shipping rather than aircraft.

For real rockets, "fuselage" seems more common, especially for rockets that fly up through the atmosphere to space.  A fuselage tends to be s cylindrical shaped structure. "Hull" or "Skin" are sometimes used for satellites or space stations.

Comment: NB in Star Trek they also used naval terminology for ranks too (e.g. "admiral") and things like "fleet" and "bridge" so they were being consistent.  But a craft with many decks, cabins etc. is more ship-like than plane-like.

Comment: While rockets often refer to a fuselage, that terminology is not often used for the parts that are meant to stay in space for an extended time. The rocket gets you up there, but you don't occupy a rocket, you occupy a capsule or some such thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer "hull", but for a different reason.

My reason is that "hull" can be used for aircraft as well as boats, but "fuselage" is much more restricted to airborne things.  For an example, see [hull loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hull_loss) (Wikipedia) - "an aviation accident that catastrophically damages the aircraft beyond economical repair".

I might use "fuselage" for things like the Shuttle, which though orbital flew to land on a runway, as well as for suborbital space planes.  Current and former crewed capsules (Dragon, Soyuz, Apollo, etc.) aren't sufficiently aircraft-like for me to think of them as having fuselages.

In the fictional sense something that feels like a naval vessel would probably have a hull, while something more plane-like might have a fuselage, especially if it was capable of atmospheric flight with wing-like parts, or manoeuvred like a plane.  So to mix up my franchises, the Enterprise would have a hull, but an X-wing could be described as having a fuselage.

If you're writing, you have options based on the impression you want to give.

Comment: Yes, I think “hull” is more appropriate because in my mind, “my” spacecraft is like the enterprise, in terms of size. Perhaps a little less but still big. Thanks 